# Fallo en CRUD con PHP y MySQL

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli, phpmyadmin

soy estudiante con poca experiencia en páginas web y estoy intentando crear una página de registro de usuario utilizando PHP y MYSQL, sin embargo, al tratar de insertar datos no hace nada, únicamente recarga la página y ni siquiera envia un mensaje de error, ¿podrían ayudarme? es para un proyecto :c.

**Esta es mi interfaz para registrar usuario**

```
    <?php 
require_once("templates/header.php");
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/registerUser.css">
</head>

<body>
    <main>
        <div class="card-header">
            <div class="rectangle"></div>
            <div class="tittle">
                <img src="resources/user.png" alt="">
                <p>REGISTRO</p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <form id="userForm">
            <div class="card-body">
 
                <h3>Usuario</h3>
                <input class="form-control" type="text" name="txtUser" placeholder="Usuario">
                
                <h3>Nombre/s</h3>
                <input class="form-control" type="text" name="txtName" placeholder="Nombre">

                <h3>Apellido</h3>
                <input class="form-control" type="text" name="txtLastName" placeholder="Apellido">

                <h3>Email</h3>
                <input class="form-control" type="text" name="txtEmail" placeholder="Email">

                <h3>Password</h3>
                <input class="form-control" type="password" name="txtPsw" placeholder="Contraseña">
            </div>

            <div class="card-footer">
                <input class="btn button" type="submit" name="btnNewUser" value="REGISTRAR">
            </div>
        </form>
    </main>

    <div class="footer">
       
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

**Esta es la clase para funcionalidad al botón**

```
    <?php
require_once("../controller/db.php");

if(isset($_POST['btnNewUser'])){
    $usern = $_POST['txtUser'];
    $name = $_POST['txtName'];
    $lastN = $_POST['txtLastName'];
    $email = $_POST['txtEmail'];
    $pass = $_POST['txtPassword'];
    
    $query = "INSERT INTO users(userID, password, typeUser) VALUES('$usern' , '$pass', 'client')";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

    if($result){
        die("Query Failed");
    } else {
        print '<script languaje = "JavaScript">';
            print 'alert("Usuario registrado")';
            print '</script>';
    }
}
?>
```

Se supone que estoy guiandome de un video, pero en el si tienen ingreso de datos y en mi proyecto no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

se recarga la página porque en la etiqueta form no declaraste ni action ni method, por lo que su method por defecto es "get" y se vuelve a cargar la página dónde estás parado y genera un query string en la url con los valores de tus inputs.
Para resolver eso, en el action debes poner el php que se ejecutará (esto es un archivo a parte .php) y toma los valores por post con su ruta si es necesario(o sea si está en una carpeta diferente al html), y en el method debes poner post.

Ej:

```
<form action="archivo.php" method="post">
...
</form>
```

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias! Funcionó perfecto.

Comment: Merece, estoy a las órdenes!

Answer (score 0):

Refresca la base para verificar, también verifica cuando creas la conexión en db que estén todos los parámetros de la base ok, como nombre de base, usuario y contraseña, por ultimo en el html el name de password es textPsw y en php lo estás invocando como textPassword, estos deben ser iguales.. Agrega espacio entre users y el paréntesis, lo mismo entre VALUES y el paréntesis.